# Convert Lighttpd rewrite to nginx

Tags: mod-rewrite, nginx, converters, lighttpd

I'm having problem in converting lighttpd rewrite to nginx.

Next line.

```
rewrite "/torrent/([0-9A-F]{2})([0-9A-F]{2})([0-9A-F]{36}).*" => "/t/$1/$2/$3.torrent";
```

some help?

Comment: Can you share with us, what kind of problem do you have? Any error message or something specific not working? What kind fo solution/rewrite have you tried already?

Comment: I really could not convert yet, I do not know how lighttpd works.
I want to work in nginx conveter, they work differently.